# Can I persist state between Jenkins shared library calls?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy

I would like to persist the state of some logic between calls in my Jenkins shared library. I don't want to pass in an object/map/... with the state in the arguments but use some kind of global variable/map for this. I failed with global varibales in the foobar.groovy below or use of environment variables. I found a work-around by creating a small helper class with a static map to store my data but this does not seem to be the right solution. Is there a cleaner way?

src/pkg/GlobalConfig.groovy

```
package pkg;

class GlobalConfig {
    // define a static map
    static Map data = new HashMap()
}
```

use map in shared library e.g. vars/foobar.groovy

```
import pkg.GlobalConfig
 
def do_something() {
    def data = pkg.GlobalConfig.data
    // do something with data
}
```

Comment: Define your global varibles with the `@groovy.transform.Field` annotation, Take a look at https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#defining-global-variables

Comment: Great, that is what I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: I just noticed this annotation in the jenkins docs and tried it but i still get inconsistent results. It seems i can declare the var before the pipeline, and use it in one stage. But then when i try to read the var, using exactly the same syntax as in the previous stage, it comes out null. I am missing something on the scope here.